# The case of Felix Exner and Brownian motion

Tags: einstein, atomic-theory

I'm reading some articles about the history of Brownian Motion, for example, that of Maiocchi (https://www.jstor.org/stable/4026755) or Genthon (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.05399.pdf), and they all cite this **Felix Exner**, son of Siegmund Exner, who made some experiments with the aim of finding a velocity for Brownian motion etc.

At the related [Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegmund_Exner-Ewarten), one reads:
"Siegmund Exner's marriage to Emilie née von Winiwarter (1847–1909) produced two children, the surgeon and university professor Alfred von Exner-Ewarten in 1875 and the meteorologist and university professor Felix Maria von Exner-Ewarten in 1876.".

I found nothing regarding the experiments with Brownian particles supposedly made by this Felix Maria. Is he the same as the one mentioned by Maiocchi et. al.? Are there some references somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exner's paper on Brownian Motion was published in [*Annelan der Physik und Chemie (1900): Volume 2 Issue 4*](https://archive.org/details/sim_annalen-der-physik_1900_2_4/page/842/mode/2up) available on archive.org (in German), starting on page 842.

So yes, it is the [Felix Maria von Exner-Ewarten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Maria_von_Exner-Ewarten) cited by Maiocchi and Genthon.

Presumably he was familiar with fluid dynamics through his work and studies in geophysics and meteorology.